# Difference between 「～かかわらず」 and 「～かまわず」

Tags: words, conjunctions

I never knew the differences between 「～かかわらず」 and 「～かまわず」 and assumed they were more or less the same until I tried saying

> *「ソフトの機能にかまわず、。。。」

and was told to use 「かかわらず」.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

〜かまわず is the 〜ず negative form of [構]{かま}う, meaning to "care about/mind/pay attention to".  It has an emotional/personal sense to it to.

> - 鉛筆で書いても構いませんか<sup>1</sup>　→　May I write with a/in pencil? ("Do you not care if I write in pencil?")
> - 彼は身なりのことはかまわない<sup>2</sup>　→　He doesn't care about his appearance.

〜かかわらず is the 〜ず negative form of かかわる, meaning "have to do with/concerning/related to" (関係のある〜・〜について・〜に関して）.  This is more objective in its use.

> - そのことには何もかかわっていません<sup>1</sup>　→　I have nothing to do with the matter.
> - それは命にかかわることだ<sup>1</sup>　→　It's a matter of life (and death).

So when you say `ソフトの機能にかまわず、。。。`, it sounds like what follows is some kind of emotional relationship to the software, when you were probably going for something like `Regardless/Irrespective of the software's functionality, ...`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Examples from プログレッシブ英和・和英中辞典
<sup>2</sup> Example from ウィズダム英和辞典／ウィズダム和英辞典

Comment: "かまわず = regardless/irrespective of".  Really?  Hard to believe your dictionary says so (because that is not true).  D.J. has the correct answer.

Comment: @l'électeur:  Why don't you try reading my answer again.

Answer (score 2):

I think the difference can be summarized by the glosses

> 「〜かかわらず」⇒ "regardless of ~"
> 「〜かまわず」⇒"without minding ~"

I guess they are somewhat similar, but using one instead of the other does result in a different meaning in every sentence I can think of.

Here's an example where 「〜かかわらず」 doesn't work:

> 私に構わず行ってください。
> "Don't mind me and go ahead."
>
> ?私にかかわらず行ってください。
> ?"Go ahead, despite me."